# S3 Bucket associated with an email

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, storage, s3-bucket

Can a s3 Bucket be associated to an email Id . 
For example, I wanted to automatically send a report to s3 , like an automate email from Oracle Business Intelligence Enterprise Edition and the email goes and sits in the s3 bucket. Is it possible ? If Yes , what is the process to be followed and how ?

Answer (score 0):

AWS S3 is simply a storage layer.  You can create a file that you can then later send as an email attachment, sure.

You'd need to figure out if you can generate that email file from the Oracle BI software you mention, and then send that to S3, either directly if it's supported, or more likely through a script/program that puts the file directly on the S3 bucket you want.

I'd start reading the docs here:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/gsg/GetStartedWithS3.html